# Saving JTable edits to two dimensional Array

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable whose cells are editable. However if i edit a cell and refresh the table. The changes are not saved. This is how i have defined the table:

```
    String [] columnNames = {"Application number",
                            "Name",
                            "date",
                            "fileLoc",
                            "Country"};
    //Data for the table
    String [][] data = table.tableArray;//tableArray is an array of array of strings.

    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    JTable mainTable = new JTable(model);
    model.isCellEditable(data.length,columnNames.length);
    contentPane.add(new JScrollPane (mainTable));
```

I've had a look online but can't seem to find any advice on saving the changes made to a cell. Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: __refresh the table.__ How are you refreshing the table?

Comment: I guess i'm not refreshing the table as such. I use frame.dispose() and then create a new frame with the table in.

Comment: Post full code that shows the problem.

Comment: I tried this, if I add a `TableModelListener` to your model, it fires when I change a cell. Your model _does_ get updated.

Comment: Model gets updated. There is no problem as you are using `DefaultTableModel`. There may be some other issue. Post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to get sooner help.

Comment: " I use frame.dispose() and then create a new frame" - is the above code inside the constructor / initialization of the new frame? If so, has the changed data been properly transferred to `table.tableArray`?

Answer (score 1):

> I guess i'm not refreshing the table as such. I use frame.dispose()
>   and then create a new frame with the table in.

- then you lost all changes made in the current DefaultTableModel
- don't top create a new JFrame with a new DefaultTableModel and a new JTable
- all changes from TableCellEditor are changes dispayed in JTables view
- JTable (with its model) is prepared for this job, don't to reacreate these Objects on runtime
- DefaultTableModel has implemented all notifiers, there no needed to override any others events, nor to fireXxxXxx() programatically, but those events are required for AbstractTableModel
- define add this code line for your JTable`mainTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);`
- DefaultTableModel respesenting your required 2D array

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is it possible to make changes made in the JTable save to the 2D arraylist the table is based on? The reason being i will need to save this array and reload it when the program is restarted. Thanks.

Comment: @Hoggie1790 Look at [getDataVector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector%28%29) to get the data that model is using.

Comment: +1, the key to solving the problem is the table client property as described in more detail in [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/).